# Почему компилятор выдаёт ошибку (T_VARIABLES) PHP

Tags: php, синтаксис

Что здесь синтаксически неправильно?
Ругается на строчку где добавляется $_GET['label'];

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
'pay01' => [
        'success_url' => 'http://pay-pass.icu/12-fixed-pay?label='.$_GET['label'], // редирект для успешной оплаты или на следующий апселл
        'fail_url' => 'http://pay-pass.icu/11-internal-account', // редирект для неуспешной оплаты
        'comment' => 'Закрепительный платёж', // коммент к платежу для юзера
        'sum' => 152, // сумма платежа
    ],
```

Comment: Но Dreamweaver показывает что в строчке ошибка

Comment: @Ипатьев по скриншоту делает конкатенацию в объявлении свойства класса с глобальной переменной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public $payments

При инициализации методов класса вы не можете использовать ссылки на другие переменные.

Comment: А как тогда можно передать параметр на страницу?

Comment: передать то можно также, через $_GET, но по данному куску непонятна логика. Вы создаете класс, с публичным свойством. Инициализировать его надо либо в конструкторе класса, либо в другом методе класса. Но опять же вся картина не видна по одному куску